# Cloud build deployment of Angular/Node.js to App Engine times out at "npm ci --quiet" command

Tags: node.js, angular, google-app-engine, deployment, google-cloud-build

I am deploying an angular/Nodejs app to App engine. The application was getting deployed to as expected about 10 months ago. Today it is timing out after 10 minutes at the `npm ci --quiet` command. This usually takes about 3 minutes to complete previously.

Have you experienced this? What is causing it to get stuck at `npm ci`?

I have tried a combination of resolution attempts including removing/adding the package-lock.json file, using different gcloud deploy images. None worked. This problem seems unique to this particular project.

Here is the package.json file

```
{
 "name": "appraisal-ui",
 "version": "0.0.0",
 "scripts": {
  "clean": "rm -rf dist && mkdir dist",
  "build:production": "npm run clean && ng build --prod",
  "build:beta": "npm run clean && ng build --configuration=beta",
  "build:cloud_test": "npm run clean && ng build --configuration=cloud_test",
  "start": "node app.js",
  "start:dev": "ng serve --port 8001 --disableHostCheck true",
  "load-pug": "node ./ng-add-pug-loader.js"
},
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
  "@angular/animations": "^12.2.10",
  "@angular/cdk": "^12.2.4",
  "@angular/cli": "~12.2.4",
  "@angular/common": "^12.2.10",
  "@angular/compiler": "^12.2.10",
  "@angular/core": "^12.2.10",
  "@angular/forms": "^12.2.10",
  "@angular/material": "^12.2.4",
  "@angular/platform-browser": "^12.2.10",
  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^12.2.10",
  "@angular/router": "^12.2.10",
  "chart.js": "^3.7.0",
  "contenteditable-max-length": "^1.0.0",
  "express": "^4.17.1",
  "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
  "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
  "material-design-icons": "^3.0.1",
  "ng-cli-pug-loader": "^0.2.2",
  "ngx-image-cropper": "^5.0.1",
  "primeicons": "^4.1.0",
  "primeng": "^12.2.1",
  "rxjs": "~6.5.4",
  "signature_pad": "^3.0.0-beta.4",
  "tslib": "^2.0.0",
  "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^12.2.10",
  "@angular/compiler-cli": "^12.2.10",
  "@angular/language-service": "~13.0.0-next.4",
  "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
  "apply-loader": "^2.0.0",
  "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
  "pug": "^3.0.2",
  "pug-loader": "^2.4.0",
  "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
  "tslint": "~6.1.0",
  "typescript": "~4.3.5"
 }
}
```

Here is the build log

[image]

Comment: The `cloudbuild.yaml` file would more useful to spot an issue here. But if the same exact build is failing on one project and succeeding on a different one, it might indicate that the issue is not with your setup but with the underlying environment where the Cloud Build build runs. In this case you might want to open a case with [Google Cloud Support](https://cloud.google.com/support-hub)

Comment: Thank you @llompalles. I temporarily got around this by switch to a flexible environment. I was using the App engine standard environment.